# REGEX - How do I make sure that a word is independent?

Tags: regex

I have a String

`man loves mango. heman is a hero.`

now I want to get the word `man`

but it's selecting `man, mango, heman`

how do I make sure that the word `man` is only selected?

the regex I'm using `[^(.*?)]\s(man)` (It's wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a word boundary

```
\bman\b
```

This matches exactly the word `man`.

Comment: I need some help here. It's working on https://regex101.com/ but for some reason not working with java (android).

Comment: I don't know what java does differently in this case. If you have a language specific regex question, you should use the appropriate tag.

Comment: i found the solution, we just need to use double slash instead of single ```\\bman\\b```

Comment: Note that the extra backslashes are not a part of the regex. Backslash is probably an escape sequence, so the extra backslash is needed to escape the backslash itself.